# How to fix Zabbix connection error to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7, zabbix

I am trying to use Zabbix to monitor my server, but I get this log error:

`20472:20230810:072630.065 \[Z3001\] connection to database ‘zabbix’ failed: \[2002\] Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’ (13 “Permission denied”)`

I have checked that the MySQL server is running and that the zabbix user has the correct permissions and password. I have also tried to access the socket using  `mysql -u zabbix -p zabbix -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` and it can work, but the log still the same.

here are some additional details:

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 0 Aug 10 07:58 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

zabbix_server.conf settings:

```
LogFileSize=0
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
DBHost=localhost
DBName=zabbix
DBPassword=password
DBSocket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

zabbix.conf.php settings:

```
<?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file.
global $DB;

$DB['TYPE']     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']     = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'password';

// Schema name. Used for IBM DB2 and PostgreSQL.
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER      = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = 'servername';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
?>
```

What could be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

i want the error can fix and zabbix can run

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I change $ZBX_SERVER ip address from localhost to my actual zabbix ip address and disable SELINUX